# pgAdmin password recovery pg_hba not working

Tags: postgresql, passwords, pgadmin

I mistakenly changed postgres user password. I tried changing pg_hba.config file and i could log into pgAdmin then reset postgres password and set back pg_hba file so that only authorized users are allowed. Unfortunately, when i opened pgAdmin it still outputs an authentication error.
What ealse should i do ?

Comment: is pgAdmin connecting as postgres?  If I understand your technique, you opened up pg_hba.conf to allow postgres to connect without a password (trusted) (local all all trust). Then you updated postgres' password (psql -Upostgres dbname -c "alter role postgres with password 'newpass'") then you reenabled (password or md5).  That should work as long as you are setting the password for the correct user.  Maybe pgAdmin has a different user? Does it have it's own password management?

Comment: Yes, pgAdmin is connecting as postgres.  
I updated postgres' password but did'nt use psql -U command. What is it for ? and how do i execute it ? Thx.

Comment: once you go in to 'trust' mode, you can use the -Uanyuser where anyuser is the user you want to connect as.  So, you want to connect as the postgres user, psql -Upostgres dbname, then to alter user password, then set the pg_hba.conf back to md5 or password.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the sequence:

edit pg_hba.conf, change the connection to trust for localhost.

Then, restart the database.

Then connect from the localhost using a command like:

```
psql -Upostgres dbname
```

Once connected, change the password:

```
alter role postgres with password 'newpass';
```

Then, you can go change pg_hba.conf back to the old configuration (not trust, probably password or md5).

restart your database

Then try:

```
psql -Upostgres dbname
```

you should be prompted for a password, give it 'newuser' (or what ever).  Then you have connected using the newly changed password.

Try connecting with pgAdmin, if it is connecting (from localhost using postgres as the connection user) then this should work.  The only other thing I can think of is pgAdmin is connecting from a foreign host, just make sure you have it covered in the pg_hba.conf file.

-g

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring **postgres** to the system user or the db user?
I assume you are talking about the db user, if you have a postgres system user, you can try to do

> user>sudo su postgres
>
> postgres>psql
>
> postgres=# alter user postgres with password 'password';

If you do not have a postgres system user or the above does not work, you should check your config. Try to modify **pg_hba.conf**, add a line like this:

> local    all      [your system user name]             127.0.0.1/32            trust

That will allow all local connections from your user to connect to postgresql db as any PSQL user, without the need for a password. Restart postgresql after changing the config file.

Comment: I am using windows 7 and yes i added the mentioned line to disable password authentication. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed! After trying the same method over and over again. I also checked the password hash for postgres definition using http://www.hashkiller.co.uk/md5-decrypter.aspx

```
CREATE ROLE postgres LOGIN
  ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'md53175bce1d3201d16594cebf9d7eb3f9d'
```

it returned postgrespostgres... I was disappointed :/ .
Then i noticed and expiration date in postgres role definition.

```
CREATE ROLE postgres LOGIN
  ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'md53175bce1d3201d16594cebf9d7eb3f9d'
  SUPERUSER INHERIT CREATEDB CREATEROLE REPLICATION VALID UNTIL '1970-01-01 00:00:00';
```

I checked at the pgAdmin role properties and found that expires at 01/01/1970 checkbox was selected. I must have selected it unwillingly.
After i deselected the checkbox, i reconnected successfully using postgres postgres.
Thanks very much for help.